# Designing simple android layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm having a little trouble laying out my android app. I didn't plan it out very well, and i'm not new to java, but im new to these android xml layouts. What i have is a horizontal linear layout parent, which contains two relative layouts. The right relative layout consists of a custom view (GridView) and under it i want 3 buttons. I've added one button (button1) to my xml file and it won't show up on screen as you can see. I'm thinking i need to set the size of my gridview some how? Its height is 2x its width. Or can i set it by pixels programatically at runtime?

I'm also thinking i sort of over complicated things at this point. Like i said i'm new to these weird layouts, im used to just using x and y offsets in .net. Maybe this could all be done in one relative layout instead of using two and nesting them inside a linear layout?

Here's what i got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <com.mydomain.tetrisv2.PreviewGridView
        android:id="@+id/previewGridView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/previewGridView1"
        android:text="Score: " />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mydomain.tetrisv2.GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't post images but heres the visual result: http://i50.tinypic.com/orscgi.png

Also side note (unrelated), this is a project for experimentation and learning purposes but are there any legal copyright repercussions to making a tetris game and putting it on the play store?

Answer (score 0):

Just change our right sides gridview's below button to this code

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" // change is here 
    android:text="Button" />
```

Hope this will help you..